# Makefile ignores the command export OMP_NUM_THREADS

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, makefile, openmp

I'm compitling and running a C++ program with openMP, with the following makefile

```
all:        
            g++ -std=c++0x -O2 -fopenmp main.cpp body.cpp -o test
            export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
            ./test
```

the variable OMP_NUM_THREADS is ignored, while if i give the three commands manually in the terminal (in the same order), the variable is taken into account and the program runs with the desired number of nodes. Running everything from the terminal has the effect that the OMP_NUM_THREAD variable is whichever value has been set manually before. In the program itself, the variable is  untouched, so the program runs just with the number of available nodes.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Ps. Does someone have a good tip on a link/document/video for a nooby introduction to bash programming?

Comment: Each line in a recipe is run in its own shell. So the `export` doesn't affect the `./test` line's shell session.

Comment: Use `env OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./test`

Answer (score 1):

Move your variable assignment and the export directive from the target part ("all") to the definition part as following:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
export OMP_NUM_THREADS

all:        
            g++ -std=c++0x -O2 -fopenmp main.cpp body.cpp -o test
            ./test
```

Comment: Better might be to scope it to the `./test` line with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./test` or similar.